# Implement an Over function

Tags: code-golf, integer, functional-programming

Over is a higher-order function in multiple languages such as [APL](https://aplwiki.com/) (`⍥`). It takes 2 functions and 2 values as arguments, applies the first function to both values, then applies the second to their result. For example, using `⍥` to represent Over:

```
1 ²⍥+ 2
```

We would first calculate `²` of each argument: `1² = 1` and `2² = 4`. We then apply `+` to these, yielding `5`.

You are to take as input:

- A [black box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/66833), \$f\$, which takes an integer as input and returns an integer
- A black box function, \$g\$, which takes 2 integers as input and returns a single integer
- 2 integers, \$a\$ and \$b\$.

You should then return the result of \$g(f(a), f(b))\$.

If you have a builtin specifically for this (e.g. APL's `⍥`, Husk's `¤` etc.), consider including a non-builtin answer as well. It might even get you an upvote :)

You may input and output in the most convenient format for your language, and in [any convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), **including taking \$a\$ and \$b\$ as a pair/list/tuple** `[a, b]`

For the sake of simplicity, you can assume that the black-box function will always input and output integers within your language's integer domain, and that \$a\$, \$b\$  and the output will be with your language's integer domain.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
f
g
a, b -> out

f(x) = x²
g(x,y) = x - y
-2, 2 -> 0

f(x) = φ(x)     (Euler totient function)
g(x,y) = 2x + y
5, 9 -> 14

f(x) = x³-x²-x-1
g(x,y) = y⁴-x³-y²-x
-1, -1 -> 22

f(x) = x
g(x,y) = x / y   (Integer division)
-25, 5 -> -5
```

Comment: Can we take `a` & `b` as an array `[a,b]`?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes you can

Answer (score 25):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 12 bytes

```hs
f?g=(.f).g.f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LCsIwELznK@bgIVE30KoHwbYfoi2Uvgz2ha2Sgt9uTJDqpQu7DLMzO3tNh1tR18aUURVwWQpZydJ0AY8EY2M3qqIdoRFgeDQ4e3ihxYksklLHW1RZbgm7D@DFjDWpaq0279DflTWu0IEnvgAn1xb4DL/6a@YgftGYKPTXejMJHHBcVFsVhTrZkU580uSJ2Tcle3L85HgX6H3H4hWVI1dP99XBRpl3VtZpNRjK@v4D)

Haskell was made for this.

Let's unpack it:

```hs
(f?g) x y =
(((.f).g.f) x) y =
(.f)(g (f x)) y =
((g (f x)).f) y =
g (f x) (f y)
```

If you're wondering what happens if we make this further pointfree in `f` and `g`, we can express `(?)` as:

```hs
\f->((.f).).(.f)
(.).(.).flip(.)<*>flip(.)
```

The flipped version of `?` that's invoked as `g?f` is a little nicer:

```hs
((.).flip(.)<*>).(.)
```

(I used [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) for these.)

*Test cases copied [from Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223888/20260).*

---

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 10 bytes

```hs
(.map).(.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LCsIwEEX3@YpZuEg0E0i0C8Hqh7QplNZqsI9gq6TgtxtTxMeisxrm3jN35pz3l2Nde3pgceqpaHLLBBXMd3FVGxvGhAzdYI7tAA5i6G8NJBIe0MIOQyeE0xxORRkGQY9BakKa3LTBW3ZgryaAC@iAZooBTRPHR417hyODBBVXmsC3fu5P5BdQS7eakIhv5wmaurA2W6PLFDqUf2FjtsFJGSdlipUc5fwWU/6w0tzDS@87Ix5p/yyqOj/1HgtrXw)

If the input `[x,y]` is a two-element list, and the binary function `g` accepts its two arguments as such a list. The main function takes is arguments as `g` then `f.

Comment: I really need to get better at pointfree

Answer (score 11):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 16 bytes

```
[ bi@ rot call ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVTNctMwEL77KTa3pERObeoDATpcGCaXXoCTJ8y4tpxoasuuJIM9JAcuPEofAHgCHgDegRcJn@S2acJPw4GdWN5In3a//XaTPElNpTavX87OXkwpraQRskmMqKTGt/JcyATnmi64krygokqTQlOZmKVb/LyRaY@uFTemq5WQhjS/bLhMeY/0sVly7ecul6bH3uxsSouqyD1vQK8qIzju3ETyfd@b0rcrGpIkxqikkUew9251HsWUNTUF9ITm1ldVTcdw17@BPN1Cgh1IfOtZs@BGCtBm1zR3jmNctg@jIwRRPGtS7gLXqoJv4J8LmtDR7a2589ZW0gwVu0qXnHiblHXBSci6Mdrri7JsGUKwkEK4@tISxf6A8mE7Qgnt1087dPZtQIthO@4cFJG6e8AsHCMRO6Vj8Loh0Av2AKkz0b8jeoRddGKPzfeP9m1t@LwpuCKz18LRX/P/gXjYImn3DzejMfihiOBkW8UK9Xe0wnNCb@A/xAo9rKTMSQORA/txyNU1ot2eBw6zJ/5nhgawlgUHszvc7ijQ/fjwhdlsnc32X3KxYOwEOKUwvNP7iRu@CB2Pf6neO3DsJpAZEzGThi8wE5l4K/Q9s2AnEV2MLB8WeetNjF/RM1KVIfzNFDTHxjthlixLTKJNkl5QLpQ25INl2ijVEU/S5eYn)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a quotation with stack effect `( x x -- x )`, two integers, and a quotation with stack effect `( x -- x )` on the data stack as input. It takes them in that order, as that allows for what I believe is the shortest code. Assuming the data stack looks like `[ + ] 1 2 [ sq ]` when this quotation is called...

- `bi@` Apply a quotation to two objects.

  **Stack:** `[ + ] 1 4`
- `rot` Move the object third from the top to the top.

  **Stack:** `1 4 [ + ]`
- `call` Call a quotation.

  **Stack:** `5`

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 10 bytes

```
map-reduce
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVBQlFpSUllQlJlXolCcWliampecWqxgzVWtYKhgpFCrEK1QXKgQC6S0FWL/5yYW6BalppQmp/7X@w8A)

Built-in.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 9):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
2 :'(u v)~v'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegrpCmYGuloK6jYKBgBcS6egrOQT5u/40UrNQ1ShXKNOvK1P9r/jdR0E5TVDDnMlHQBdEA)

Non-built-in solution. This is an explicit conjunction that takes two functions on two sides and evaluates to a train that acts like "u over v", but with flipped arguments.

```
x ((u v)~v) y
x (u v)~ v y
(v y) (u v) x
(v y) u v x
```

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 1 byte

```
&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegrpCmYGuloK6jYKBgBcS6egrOQT5u/9X@a/43UdBOU1Qw5zJR0AXRAA)

J's built-in conjunctions can be assigned to a variable, unlike in Dyalog APL.

Comment: "unlike in *Dyalog* APL" ― works fine in, say, NARS2000.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```javascript
(f,g,x,y)=>g(f(x),f(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5BDsIwDLvzihyTKgVtsGN33D@msVagaUVsQs3rS7pdQIKDFdmxLd/7V78Mz9tjtXO8jrlzGT0HTizk2oAeE7FHIcpDnJc4jccpBuwwgWshGVMzYGIQ2jhYEAarYk10@J04q6kEy1FUnwVizGV/F5cy2GxaWRX86fyecNonNAyNrn4D)

Comment: Ninja'd by ten seconds :/

Comment: No need to Over-complexify, life is Overly simple

Comment: [20](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9m@18jTSddp0LT1i5do0IvN7FAI01T839yfl5xfk6qXk5@uoabRoWCrZ1ChZaWkY6CRnSFjkJlrCZYREFXoVJHIVoXKG4Uq6nJhV2XMVAZSDOIAmJDVEMqtbRMIApA6oA8BbBCkLFAlbqGuMxFd4o@1CmmOgqmQD3/AQ)

Comment: due to rule clarify

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```hs
(f!k)x=k(f x).f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LCsIwELznK6bgIVFTSLUHwfRHtIFiWw19ia2yBf@9Jkj10oVdhtmZnb1lfVXU9TTxMqgE6YqXIBGW09ANtmgHEDT6Z4OTwhstjtKhMKR0i@sld4Tba6iUsU7zQDDWZLZ1lrzD/WGdf4UO3EQCXPp2IGL41V8z5/EzYZRJtKbNKBDjsKh2KpmQ2UkykSSpxOwbzV56fvS8D1TfsXjF5sjty38Vu6jpAw)

*-1 thanks to Wheat Wizard repatterning the use of infix*

Comment: Also worth pointing out this exists in the standard library as 'on' in Data.Function

Comment: @rak1507 Thanks! Like, actually, thanks--I knew something like that had to exist but instead of searching the type signature I've been stuck on the idea that it has to be one of those infix operators from `Control.Arrow` :P

Comment: [You can shave off a byte with virtually no modification](https://tio.run/##bU7LCsIwELznK6bgIVFTSLUHwfRHtIFiWw19ia2yBf@9Jkj10oVdhtmZnb1lfVXU9TTxMqgE6YqXIBGW09ANtmgHEDT6Z4OTwhstjtKhMKR0i@sld4Tba6iUsU7zQDDWZLZ1lrzD/WGdf4UO3EQCXPp2IGL41V8z5/EzYZRJtKbNKBDjsKh2KpmQ2UkykSSpxOwbzV56fvS8D1TfsXjF5sjty38Vu6jpAw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```rust
|f,g,x,y|g(f(x),f(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCsIwEITveYp4y8oGSrwZ6qtIAtlS0IXmB1qMzx5TKogwDMzHzMSSciOWTzezgpd8hCzpSqy65osBfeuOR8Af@Etjq4QTrrjVSZFaAUltAM2K/S0txcUwysqVz/xlxctOHPrqtLfCpRRivofl1PfHAHsHDWoDOIAV7/YB)

An anonymous function that has the signature

```rust
fn(fn(i32)->i32,fn(i32,i32)->i32,i32,i32)->i32
```

Don't you love it when the function signature is twice as long as the function itself?

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
{⍺⍺/⍵⍵¨⍵}
```

```apl
{⍺⍺/⍵⍵¨⍵}
 ⍺⍺          left operand (function argument)
   /         reduce
    ⍵⍵       right operand
      ¨      each
       ⍵     right argument
```

APL has a builtin for this, ⍥, but here's a non builtin solution as an operator taking an array of arguments.

Alternative 'proper' definition: `{(⍵⍵⍺)⍺⍺⍵⍵⍵}`, or more readably as `{(⍵⍵ ⍺) ⍺⍺ ⍵⍵ ⍵}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpHvbuASP9R71YgOrQCSNT@/6@dpqhgomAOAA)

Comment: [`⎕/⎕¨⎕`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jvqn6QHxoBZAAifxXAIMCLhMFcy5FLm0A)

Comment: @Adám not a fan particularly, you can post that as a separate answer if you want

Answer (score 6):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```lisp
(λ(f g x y)(g(f x)(f y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYtLCoQwEET3OUWBm66FCz8XEqcNg6ISRJKzeYe5UuyRwVkIRVEF74WuH3XLxdTNHuE6Tl46vGfFsmvI8jlkgEdEonibkVaJZKZz8mVgDCQSUkI0rpvBDe9Z06oif5i5fzCh5dNJl2NGWVmYTw)

`λ` is 2 bytes, BTW.

Pretty self-explanatory, but:

```lisp
(λ(f g x y)(g(f x)(f y)))  Anonymous function submission
(λ                      )  Lambda;
  (f g x y)                accept functions f, g and arguments x, y and return
           (g          )   g(
             (f x)           f(x),
                  (f y)            f(y))
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(f,g,a,b)g(f(a),f(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BCgIxDEX3nqIgAwkkaKvd2asMbcUWNzMw6NCevjYDiojb/Pdeljavt0VdWLX0nK6P@zxBokyBImZIEJASRMQNg@Q@UMEyGspfB6pYuFJwbCg6g2qvjrt/2om7yoX1r17HM8tcZZaQ7iHWUjLmnfLgu@eHw@C3X7YzVhC27QU)

No surprises here. In a future version of R, `function` will be replaceable with `\` (which is supposed to look like a lambda).

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 10 bytes

```
#2@@#/@#3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CoMwFIV3nyJwIUvvpeRahw4tLt0tHUsDQRQD1YLEKcRXT5M4Hc53fmbjpmE2zvYmjrcI3LZwbqGWsVvt4t5A9zGhj9xfvVl2X3nQLFEAQRZPjBwCVv6xfYe1mywKhtORNXgtEeia0oqAVF6yvlBBnFk5UUjqqCb73H7ODosr7w2KJoQqxD8)

Input `[f, g, {x, y}]`.

Comment: Nice ... argh, `Inner` is so close to doing this task

Answer (score 5):

### SKI-calculus, 71 bytes

```
S(S(KS)(S(K(S(KS)))(S(K(S(K(S(KS)))))(S(K(S(K(S(KK)))))(S(KS)K)))))(KK)
```

Edit: Another go at hand-translating the lambda calculus expression into SKI using the rules in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis), this time arriving at the same answer as @Bubbler.

Comment: According to [SKI interpreter by aditsu](http://ski.aditsu.net/), your expression evaluates to `(x0->(x1->(x2->x0(x1(x2)))))` which doesn't look quite correct.

Comment: Working 71 bytes: `S(S(KS)(S(K(S(KS)))(S(K(S(K(S(KS)))))(S(K(S(K(S(KK)))))(S(KS)K)))))(KK)`. I guess there must be a language like Binary Lambda Calculus that can express SKI calculus in binary or something...

Comment: ...and there's [Binary Combinatory Logic](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Binary_combinatory_logic). Time to build an online interpreter...

Comment: @Bubbler Nice, I hadn't realised that `S(KK)I` is just `K` for a start, so I'll take another crack at it.

Comment: @Bubbler OK I've tried again and come up with your answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 23 bytes

```lisp
(q((f g x y)(g(f x)(f y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxDoAgEAR7XrHlrZ1@hDdgiISEoKIF9/rzbCaTzLy1a6vPZSYZUW6RAwUTSimukw41aWfKaHUfaShDkIh/9br4O0kiYcVG@wA)

### Ungolfed

```lisp
(lambda (f g x y)     ; a lambda function taking four arguments
  (g (f x) (f y)))    ; apply f to x, f to y, and g to the results
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>54</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>37</s></sup> 36 bytes

```c
o(f(),g(),a,b){return g(f(a),f(b));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJLjtNAEN3nFG8iRWo73ZrYkMVgGhaIU5BZtL9jTegM7QC2Ii/YcCDgBFxg7jAHwVS37cQZDUKTqO1UV716r@olEclW6aLrdixnHi/oKB57B5PtPxuNgm6Vx3MWe17UdqXeo/pkWO3hgKGkho86QjuzybTMc1bz5iwv0Iz5IkmZ4ogn@RgXEiu8dbmYQ2Fh86@gRtDdTcm0RdjAQCKIkO8MmI1LisOIXq@hIyyXpWuNpXT9NAddSAdpR0ZzbLzbNiuSi6ne0M6D5UmzrQrOR/bpS2MNTzrBtDgcN9D4kroMoMZveogDud8jqEzP2x/v9T4tvzze56VT5go@qlIzb3aYgT7JjTI@PbPkNjMfrmkvh/mmfh9u6qt3dNZzjmn8Yt5GDudMpeodI2u5s5BDhByhdyrIqGDVh3eGLnI2z61oifr3D07/EydS9m4PcIg3WKRYVBtN3BU/aqukzK6puWvXU5PHvPeDY81xNVBb2uDlk7z33@lNLM6rHvQsQutqT0laRWDPhDQM/zHsT0EDi9oCjkM3D99@CZtqbGrs9hw1ZcoHt@3uaJb1RItYP63lbO2X/dot9L/EbfcnybeqqDrx9S8)

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*
*Saved a byte thanks to [jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)!!!*

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVDLToQwFN3zFTckk7TkNpEaF4bgxvgVMgumQ5E4wghjbENY@EvqF/gpfoh4Wx66MULa9Pacc8@5VaJUahwbprHEHHe8qk@gGceS8aTP05JplnPUbMd5MowO7R5bZnjfFqentgYDEZhkCIJ9pTUzaHkPKyTAOujYHGzsNCsS0U/ovIOIF5qcW9gotclCt5GdyJ7uz47/kFc140EfAH3qLm8j2gt1X7S3W0ihDzNzIzNzeU3rIkT4XZ@HQ@J1fiJiN4zmQnBTIAiJIPkPoSDC2VQeW7rQLKRZOd2aj1eE0od2lYs3y0FcwWYPmy6rybvDNVuXpsWWmvt2k7V/IAT/ACSP3ZrtnbWUf3i/CfIXxgnWDPbz5V04yDpo6fZvmiEYv5Q@5GU3iudv)

Comment: @dingledooper Nice - thanks! :D

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P18jTUNTJx2IE3WSNKuLUktKi/IU0oGiiZo6aRpJmprWtf9zEzPzNDQV9PT0/v9LTstJTC/@r1sOAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

\$ a \$ and \$ b \$ are inputted as a tuple (called \$ x \$).

```python
lambda f,g,x:g(*map(f,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3NCoMwEITveYo5JmGX1rReBK8@RS@R1h/wJ5RIk6e3qSAohVnY3ZmPcdF382TWqnysgx3rp0VDLYWilXq0TjYUlFo/XT@8kBUimWgJ0hJqwrx4p1Cin9zipaK/RcC9@8mjkgdOJaTc2L0xFAhaG7GfFNODo2BDSLqKU@7GvzAHzk5A1PrOmx03W2QETmPMET93XH4dOSGJ8y8)

Comment: You can save a byte by taking input as a list [a,b]

Comment: @rak1507 Yeah, just noticed it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ñ€ç/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef804bi2VSpAwrVfLwoswrXhuosyKjRSwqRVXy//w5HigqzDpy////8tMSwgLTE)

Takes `f` on the first line, `g` on the second line, and the code is on the third line (this is standard for Jelly). Also, takes the arguments together as a list

```
 €    For each of the arguments
Ñ     Apply the next link (wraps around to `f`)
   /  Reduce by (for a pair, applies dyad to the first and second element of the list)
  ç   Apply the last link (`g`)
```

Also works:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ÑçÑ}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8b/Jwx7ZQLYdDW@P1uXQObX24q9tIyyTo0JLQeP3/hyceXn54Yu3///91DYEIAA)

```
Ñ     Apply `f` (to the left argument, since it's called as a monad)
 çÑ}  2-2 chain - given dyads x, y, computes x(a, y(a, b)) if the chain's current value is a and the right argument is b
 ç    Apply `g` to the current value (f(left)) and
  Ñ}  A dyad formed from a monad by ignoring the left argument
```

Basically, `Ñ}` is `(l, r) -> f(r)`, so this ends up evaluating as `λ x y -> g(f(x), (λ a b -> f(b))(x, y))` which simplifies to `λ x y -> g(f(x), f(y))` as required.

(These chaining rules are absolutely beautiful. Thank you Dennis for Jelly :P)

Comment: There is also `ÑçÑ}` that takes `a` on the left and `b` on the right :)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing lol, I am currently editing that in with a description :P

Comment: There is also [`ñçñ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8f2irycMd20K1HA5tjdfn0jm09eGubiMtk6BDS0Lj9f8f3nh4@eGN////1zUEIgA), but that requires `f` to be forced as a monadic link (prefixed with `µ`) if it has any different behaviour when run monadically/dyadically

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```scala
_ map _ reduce _
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzVWWmKOQZqURnFoY7ZlXEqsDJGztgISOBogAYk0wF0La/o9XyE0sUIhXKEpNKU1OVYj/X1CUmVeSk6eRBjJCw1jHVFNHN14nXjteU5Or9j8A)

Takes ([a,b],f,g). There’s more ways to do this but I’m on mobile so I’ll add them later

Answer (score 4):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 21 bytes

```
(f,g,a)=>g(*map(f,a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc0xDoQgEAXQnlP8EshQ4G6LFzFbUCixEAgxRk7PDhptJn8yL/NzSXuKLR1zgWtyoUBeuTFIvfnMq1eqLXA44UYeWuMDc4fhCgZWBAbyJFTVVe3H76M6ry8XIpc17rL38XcEwmQswdgfF/0B)

Time to bring out this garbage again :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 bytes

```
n!aa!a!
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%22Code%3A%22d%0An%21aa%21a%21%0A%7DY%0A%22Testcases%22d%0A%7B-%7D+2N+%7BJ%7D+2+y%21P%0A%7BH%2B%7D+5+%7B%3At%7D+9+y%21P&i=)

A full program which can be executed as a block as well.

accepts the arguments as `g x f y`.

Comment: Cant this be packed?

Comment: doesn't make sense to pack something that can be reused. It takes its arguments from the stack, so I think it doesn't make sense to pack here.

Comment: "a full program" submission can surely be packed to save a byte.

Comment: nah. not doing it.

Comment: Okay boomer :p. How about explaining how the link works

Comment: multiline code is the same as single line code. the program is wrapped in a block and stored in register `Y`. Then the test cases are pushed to the stack and the block is executed on each of them.

Comment: Ah very nice. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->f,g,x,y{g[f[x],f[y]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfYftf1y5NJ12nQqeyOj06LboiVictujI2tvZ/gUJGtK5dRXWFlpZRrQ6QBVRRoVtZq2Oko2sU@x8A)

Or:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->f,g,*x{g[*x.map(&f)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfYftf1y5NJ11Hq6I6PVqrQi83sUBDLU0ztvZ/gUJGtK5dRXWFlpZRrQ6QpVNZXaFbWatjpKNrFPsfAA)

Comment: Since you're allowed to take an array of arguments you can [omit the first `*`](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfYftf1y5NJ12nojo9WqtCLzexQEMtTTO29n@BQka0rl1FdYWWllGtDpClU1ldoVtZqxNtpKNrFBv7HwA) in your second solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>8</s> 3 bytes

```
M$R
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=M%24R&inputs=&header=%CE%BB2%7C-%3B%20%0A2%202N%22%0A%CE%BB%C2%B2%3B&footer=)

Takes `[g, [a, b], f]`. If reduction was reversible, then this would be 2 bytes.

### Explained

```
M$R
M   # map f over [a, b]
 $R # reduce that by g
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel (Insider Beta), 29 bytes

```
=LAMBDA(f,g,a,b,g(f(a),f(b)))
```

`LAMBDA` is only available through Excel Insider Beta.  The functions have to be defined as names to work.  In my case, I defined a name q that is equal to the above and then used the formula `=q(LAMBDA(x,x^2),LAMBDA(x,y,x+y),1,2)` in a cell.  This could also be done by defining the names `a=LAMBDA(x,x^2)` and `b=LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)` and then use the formula `q(a,b,1,5)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 11 bytes

Takes input as `Ꙫ(g)(f, [a, b])`.

```
g->g<*..map
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/auYqBVuFmP/punbpNlp6ermJBf@LC4FCFQq6dgoVWlpGXAVFmXklGkCFGrqaGsWFOgrRRjoKukaxmpr/AQ)

`<*..` is the *multi-arg backward function composition*, which makes this function equivalent to

```
g->*args->g(*map(*args))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
₂₁⁰₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1FT06OmxkeNG4Dk/0fTFnJp//9v@N8IAA)

Black-box functions are supplied as sequential lines in the code (in the footer in the TIO link), input values are given as program arguments.

```
₂₁⁰₁     # 2 argument function: second argument is implicit
   ₁     # perform function ₁ using second argument
 ₁⁰      # perform function ₁ using first argument
₂        # perform function ₂ using the last 2 values as arguments
```

Comment: I'm sure you can use F instead of Ẋ to return a value instead of an array.

Comment: @Razetime - Yes, you're right, that's much better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 24 bytes

```
func[f g x y][g f x f y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vfllpk9T@tNC85Ok0hXaFCoTI2Ol0hDchIAzL//wcA)

This version doesn't work in TIO (Red is not up-to date), that's why I provide a screenshot from my Red GUI console:

[image]

## TIO compatible version, 28 bytes

```
func[f g x y][do[g f x f y]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY69DoMwDIT3PMWNFIkBWpY8RtcoA8UJygIl/Ch5@tRBrURbyZbsu@8se0PpbkhpMe3Gy2S3sVcWAwKiVjSpAZZny5tOyyxxAEGrgBJBCxu@pBJXVCgO88JT4K4zFT9YPhszeHuDHMlkwSLikdHC0emqFuLp3bgifwi5zJAdEWo0f/qyPVbf9Suq5se1IXdEVXO9nbPvCJLc7shwtkWbXg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```julia
F(!,+,a,b)=!a+!b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BasMwEEX3PsWYbCQ8irBi0yQ0pZvmGAFFkWw1tlRimcon6wF6MNcOhTqF2Qzvf3j/vW@szOM4HkmKGUo800Mqs/Q8JoZECgeIJ5FUJOJwf9iQvHa1/4QjMVghEyhoMkXdTLu@JZa9VOpCLDr6LDDfT2AFb32jbxB8sNoFML1TwXoH5uZbqEP46PacK3/RlW/MugtSXXVUtXSVXivfcsm3m7J44rttWeR/MiJCBo8@Je7uOr/mGzbZs8gWpeFUsBkMM3jckk@3aC9Ww/cX/B9eYknHHw)

**Previous answer, 17 bytes**

```julia
g*f*x=g(f.(x)...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BbsMgEEX3PsVI3UDCgHCMmkRN1U2vEckigEltqGKs4pP1AD2Ya0ddON3N6M3XvH8dWl/LPE1uYzf55IjlJFPOOZ3sPMAJ8rksHMlsvC84Fm99E79guSdYMihpUVgSFtoPHfH46vSFeBboS8nkcQZP8D605gYpJm9CAjsEnXwMYG@xgyalz/4ohI4X42JreZ9q/WGyburgDNexE7XY71T1LA57VcmVzDbDFh6EFDvcdf7MdzjbY8ZVaDxXuIBxAQ9dJEO5Cq/@wM83/OutGCo6/QI)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program version of [rak1507's implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223885/43319).

```apl
⎕/⎕¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jvqn6QHxoBZAAifxXAIMCLhMFcy5FLm0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 10 bytes

```
${z|x|>&y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwFEX3fMUjFBeTSqsuhbqIxUkE3R5PKDVUQVppoyTWfntMURAd7nLuuTfXOi9OymVJ6oLu8TTPxcj2bqPUscXgei1KYjvdnKtyX2e3qtDnukJDkKSwuueXtWoU8qDjMAbjw3tOjG29r/eq1cu8VS2Ogi7DMAz/f9KFEWCpF4AMABCQm0PMBXAjLSePZSwgJiDx7afSO9LIaPDsYSYHZAf0XkQCZPQzGcTsUtcNmomlz@9cwNxbjMi9AA)

Takes input as `F[f, g, [a, b]]`, where `F` is the above function.

This is two separate pipes: The vectorizing pipe `|`, and the regular pipe `|>`. `z|x` pipes each element of `z` into the unary function `x`, i.e., `Map[x, z]`. Then, this array is piped to `&y`, which passes each element of the array as a separate parameter.

### Alternatives

`${&y!x=>z}`, 10 bytes. Same input as above.

`{_2@@Map[_]}`, 12 bytes. Takes parameters `f` and `g`, returns a function which takes a tuple `[a, b]` as input.

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache) (builtin), 3 bytes

```
`#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCsIwFET3@YpLLKKYVFrtplA3YnElgu4uVyw1qCCttFESfPx6TVEQXczmzJnJtM7yg2rSOGm2nbhZKLWr0Tuf8z2xla6OxX5dppci18eyQEMQJzC7Zqe5qhRy78ZhAMaFPzgxtnS@XqtaT7Na1dj1br3/j2Ri4D6B7jPto@/7lh4CkAEAAnKzCbkAbqTl5LAMBYQEJL79SDpHGhm0nt2MZYtsi96LQIAMfiatmJ7KskIztPT5jQREzmJEzQs)

Simple quote-operator. Called as `` (`#:)[g, f][a, b] ``.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 11 bytes

```
[@:g"!...g]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv@xWjF5NDAkk95SA99SdKLUVLDyKGNgWD5NvjNoJ62J0d5g3sEobLbbzm3NZu2u@01lOXa9cQCSF6CyvxwhOOx@KMVFwsPkIhSQJzBr35gRWDH1yxKpgN/BYjjiWvSh7/uAQpiVo3j36GXwMOUCde28mPNXisocN98JTf)

Simple anonymous function. Takes input on stack as `(a b) f g`.

Works by storing `g` as a temporary function variable. Then, applies the `"` transformation on function `f`, which makes it apply on each element its called on. `!` calls this function `f"` on the tuple `(a b)`. Then, we simply put these two elements on the stack and call `g`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
#define o(f,g,a,b)g(f(a),f(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzNCsIwEITveYqlIuzqetBr8WE2v@RgqmkLgdJnj0kFL8POzLdjbsGYWk/W@ZgcTOg5sLCmgB6F2KMmqjEtMH9WyQ77WWjLbllzgnIp4656JtYenXBX/SfkqhtxIC@JCZA2Bd1lNz8n/K1y@@Y7P2hU8M6t9YDD2Q7coJbt9Qs)

Answer (score 2):

## Standard ML, 24 bytes

```
fn(f,g,a,b)=>g(f a)(f b)
```

---

#### [Concurr pre-release](https://codeberg.org/Wezl/Concurr/commit/22c5242bfe500ba531b6f3808ec60af1f0e74386), 50 bytes

```lisp
$lambda\f:lambda\g:lambda\a:lambda\b::g(:f a)$:f b
```

Wow that's horrible.

Comment: `fn(f,g)=>g o map f` if you use lists, but I haven’t counted to see if it’s actually shorter. Also with a tuple you can do `g(f a,f b)` which is certainly one shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

As far as I know, Japt does not support taking functions as inputs, or at least I couldn't find a way that actually works. To sidestep this problem, I've moved the blackbox functions into the code header while excluding them from the byte count. Their definition or form is not important for the implementation itself. Hope this is valid, otherwise I don't think Japt can compete.

The functions are to be stored in `V` and `W` respectively.

```
mV rW 
mV    // Map the array of input numbers through V
   rW // then reduce the result with W.
```

Shaved off a byte thanks to Shaggy by taking the input as an array instead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPnPFWbrEKGlZcQVDqS1I//nhikUhf//H22so2ASCwA)

Comment: If they were all built-in Japt methods, they could be taken as input strings. Consensus does allow, though, for black box functions to be assigned to pre-defined variables so we're OK there. Although, you could take advantage of mult-line code to allow for both options, [like so](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=CkBYsgpAWC1Z&code=Tm1WIHJX&input=LTIsMg). You can also save a byte by taking the integer inputs as a single array and ditching the `N`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for the tip on the empty leading line in the header, didn't know I could avoid overriding `U` that way, that's the reason I went with `N`.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
q~%*
```

Inputs are: function *g*; array of numbers; function *f*. Functions are defined as [code blocks](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Data%20types%20and%20literals/).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOVev//2rdWq5oXSMFo1iuaiPlWgA) Or verify all test cases: [1](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOVev//2rdWq5oXSMFo1iuaiPlWgA), [2](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOVev//@oYIy3tWq5oUwXLWK5qqwhNHQ3r6tw0Q92I3DQ1xVpVK@1aAA), [3](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOVev//2qrSBPlGKsIY2XdSCNl3QjdWq5oXUMFXcNYrmqQaARYUKMWAA), [4](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7BOVev//2r9Wq5oXSNTBdNYrupaAA).

#### Explanation

```
q   e# Read all input as an unevaluated string
~   e# Evaluate. Pushes a code block, an array, and a code block to the stack
%   e# Map (second function over the array)
*   e# Reduce (the array using the first function)
    e# Print (implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 17 bytes

```
{&^g(|@^x».&^f)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wi0uXaPGIa7i0G49tbg0zdr/xYmVCmka1SrxhzbV6ihUq8RVKOgqqMRVAjk2ukYKRnaa1goINZt1QQqBhK4hRHXlo8YtukBNIJlKkEwFWKOhgq4hUOd/AA)

`&^f` and `&^g` are the function arguments to the over function, and `@^x` is the list of arguments to `f`.  `@^x».&^f` maps the arguments to `f` over `f`, and `|` flattens that list into the arguments to `g`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```clj
#(%(%2%3)(%2%4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxCsMwDEbhXaf4IQikQha3OY3xUGoXXIztpAokp3fT5Q3f8F6lffYtDYnpDRuTsLDju/77UB1KEts3rfAHPPkZk9zAYMXs4AL5dW@GHFO1bOeFC5ZAIZD0LVcrFfLsvZwwHHr9fg)

Takes inputs in the order of \$g, f, a, b\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```lisp
(λ(f g x)(apply g (map f x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpNCoAgFATgvacYaNG8wE03klKJykQi7GzdoSuZtpufL5lptWfpNhM80l8UZ@uWYHFcNhW@Dx08stDEuN01cjcRri4iRZRic6gOzAIOyO2CRk89YqzoAw)
Takes a and b as a list i.e. `'(a b)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 41 bytes

```lua
function k(f,g,x,y)return g(f(x),f(y))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoAgEEX3fYXLmZhauO9johyRQkGUxq836UFt7zmcu@e5Vs5@SS54tQGTJaGC0aQcvbLAIEgMBdH4tfL0um1@HOlFNdbZH/sKMpSLujAe0SUD98egSSPWEw)

Answer (score 2):

## MMIX, 32 bytes (8 instrs)

Takes arguments `f`,`g`,`x`,`y`.

(jxd)

```
00000000: fe040004 c1070200 bf060000 c1080300  “¥¡¥Ḋ¬£¡Ḃ©¡¡Ḋ®¤¡
00000010: bf070000 bf050100 f6040004 f8060000  Ḃ¬¡¡Ḃ¦¢¡ẇ¥¡¥ẏ©¡¡
```

Disassembly:

```
on  GET    $4,rJ
    SET    $7,$2
    PUSHGO $6,$0    // $6 = f(x)
    SET    $8,$3
    PUSHGO $7,$0    // $7 = f(y)
    PUSHGO $5,$1    // $5 = g($6,$7)
    PUT    rJ,$4
    POP    6,0      // return $5,f,g,x,y,$4
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PPL v1.0.11](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ppl-lang), 31 bytes

```js
fnv(f,g,x,y){
returng(f(x,y))
}
```

This must be run on PPL version 1.0.11 (or later) because the ability to pass functions as parameters was only added in v1.0.11. Fairly simple, if you can get past the unreadability of the "mashing tokens together".

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 30 bytes

```java
(f,g,x,y)->g.a(f.a(x),f.a(y));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZCxboMwEIb3PIWXSjac04KUoXFAbSNV6tAp2aoOhgBySkxkTGSEeHZqExJlaSN03Pn8f/@dvOcnTve7n@HlvZGpFpXk5YfUmcp5miFxrV5X27jbIo63yBDW31G/3ahhi9r7xPpCuEEcnEFiydTGztLHJilFitKS1zX65EJ2U6fWXNt0qsQOHWwfb7QSsvj65qqoSbdeuWFFpuIqGnAOBRhoCY2LOce5DUPApZYQNmzaWmeHedXo@dF66FLiyklobDwD@Awa2gINIbTA7A/Arbdc6gsResZvYQHP/yDnGZ6hY9Dgwrbe@NHz5ViBvaXBHa/rto9u2wUsrL6fTW9lpajA7s9hPCSkEznmUfREVKYbJVHCpqLAyQMHbukbWI@wtJRNKgpYXqmxJaKQiZVkwvdHSzsFJImigCjfZ/3kqVjfD78)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 27 bytes

```python
lambda f,g,a,b:g(f(a),f(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
RM
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

The perfect job for a functional language. Here is an example program with \$a = 1\$, \$b = 2\$, \$f(x) = -x\$, \$g(x, y) = x - y\$, producing the correct result of
`1`:

```
RMw1 2'Nx'-
```

Explanation:

```
RM # Takes input as [a, b], f, g
 M # Map the input with the first function
R  # Reduce the result by the second function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 21 bytes

```
$[f g x y][g f x f y]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?gJUF9D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda f,g,a,b:reduce(g,map(f,[a,b]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfYRvzPycxNyklUSFNJ10nUSfJqig1pTQ5VSNdJzexQCNNJxooFqup@b@gKDOvRCFDA6q6wqpCRwHG1qm0qtCv1FHQNTLVUTDV/A8A)

Some approach different than dingledooper

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda f,g,a,b:g(f(a),f(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfYRvzPycxNyklUSFNJ10nUSfJKl0jTSNRUydNI0lT839BUWZeiUKGBlRNhVWFjgKMrVNpVaFfqaOga2Sqo2Cq@R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-P`, 16 bytes

```sh
eval g '`f '$@\`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgG6BgqGDElaahmZqcka@gEq1iqKClpWAUy5WOLKStoGIU@z@1LDFHIV1BPSFNQV3FISbh/38A)

Expects the functions to be [predefined as `f` and `g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707).

The `-P` option makes the `$@` array expand to wrap the word around every element, e.g.  `x$@y` with `A B` makes `xAy xBy` instead of `xA By`. This allows it to generalise implicitly for more than 2 inputs.

---

For 1 byte less, you can have an uninteresting answer that only works with 2 inputs:

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 15 bytes

```sh
g `f $1` `f $2`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgqGDElaahmZqcka@gEq1iqKClpWAUy5WOLKStoGIU@z9dISFNQcUwAUwZJfz/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Knight, 22 bytes

```
O E++P" "+=f+P" "+P+fP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9u4Ff2eX0GzWYsQaVp2d7YTybQncZ1OpruOG3ubmUpKBIKQxA0FKnzYyUrsX3fvBfgAJUtOP9gmiYP7wrkP@A96T1OWhMvsSMQBf2QRTVPjnyKczbOrJIkTg3/LuAhSQ76tCgW4oUnK2@vangr1IRdZuHged5slnC5WLBZpluQsixOLklU2D1M3jfOEcY8WsBIuP87DjKdLyrhVri9oxubW8SdrOBqPhqMUvhf9sb3@y/DTSIy71kisXxLSPSbFkvMvsJrwLE@EoQkf9sbrtcijqFDCfId5PbKKeGZQz3f5N84sDU4GpQjc4nkevcCHvg7xtGc3zX2w3aKgxo24mGVz4tAhG5Mii8HxUMyetKooZDiMO284Hqgw/ZtGOV@lGc1CZizxBCyfrHx3KzSDKUTwniZgf29Az@5KvQNq28ov5t0N6ditZAzCqcVIaQMrNP@KJBcy1En8YAj@oFhQBNzPZ0983@GRFOI2i4V4EgA/hf/kCnwtSq78Cm4mNKrppIKyQZ00X/LEIo4U8TmgGQUGKVc04U@YW743@1q2XucLH@Tqq5q9b@I44lS0lvnXCO0pEdQIwUwqGI@nyj3N7sNDzVqglXqq3Ebhtc9lDLaoUFG2SYq7t2MyfH30n3H32DmpmUsPD/HMUKZl3pmojRRBvljWzkwqZ17KNCvIpIiyeePKQWPr4SGV5zPT1w19/UABijt3madzC0WTgWL3lbcqSna/C7jINo71OQeH9OjPz2P83Tt69Rmc3HRRCgWzin0ECREEBGlHQG4NpyHgVBAUDkMB5oYzgXKuhs3KuOaYMrO1hil2H4eB0TvAaFdWDpoM0oulNfldfBHxgzDC2gqj0zKjM2kiKk0lVRy1KP4oUUaBvR06CFxJeEo26VEuNOygQaCdfrW/YYFNMb1JAdVwL@6oxC3yaC@uW@KC8F53CL5hpFtBrjb/RrO5CxwQTJNzDL7tOgTzkgoRZwbogJgb/nfjT57EJhgXBz@qtNH0E31WEcjNo1hTtIwfdihq5K7XBxY965Efcrfb/QF/@bdlLJB2NOPSEiOLoXYJPgMW3XMDrOIJWBftyPgzeTY7C8K5Wq7J21D3GjrOfu5qtbQm73VZ4IjiLQpppXuV7djPNnhsItgi5r46LeWVrj4TOBYvwEwut7hmHYH/c1cVGHyvIgN96dnAIEt8j2rV3@yMCQxG6eh23L0go5Nj51QSCCMBHPJ1yoAGnATUdEBdNS0h2Oxgg2Drdcfs4ANp3GmmQCxYYNUiFMCZwPiax0AdLlic42ce9I2XK1pMWt1UGt7OEeekR9br3kaxKZvyvmKD1k9KQKlpu4IgqNHlJnzJKTQHWUj2slmbXPaQWkNVRwgfyAAGMcDT4Pa7YH1aeAn/mocJt8xpahJnhfOlXPK1JTYPo@DzMokZTxH19vfry7t3769vm375FjJ7X7vUGKEOE8baWszQ1zqSPFVt6BtoHLroy@yy1y45VuzgOJDigIkvAQyYwRmrBsygGjCnnrTIrUxBZQfTHdT5LYR@KmYGTWb5AoeAl6vAPikMUGJM0UvofD42vAFXYZ2SQjtWDITFHN/hG20ePrGNVo/iPKqeBV1wz1fPoDr12PaIKDdYruvWqLqCqKJsovYsjIVl2rXUOjy@UQ16ciu1PdMxTNt3lYy649rmVg167//BWeaGqaSsAyNMMS1VGR/QN7KCmJ5gz6muFRvTuGVegy3GIoc5y4ds/EZZFn03oLQbbE4TeIOhIorFDIrOoGEGHXt@owojUncg/UzLhIJ7m@Vr1Cd6gWnmHDXHD548f/M6Nu5RMlTCPArQVqkiOIBiWCYSRpk4HyzzxnQs4p2XtxjTdHzvTT6d8sSlURQzC4bcIMbIUKsH59@DqdcBgvtw@yI@WPtlwGzw7wHyi1sn0EnlirwAuZhJH0NIcHMkTEKYx9w0CuFC1XOMo2Z6rkoJI4U06YMyqdV3p1EMnv18@urnV7/87fTVL135NaEiiBcYJLnxynSod46Roa0IwlrndQfX6gxW4SsN8PX2BCovKouUCHeaxItLOOFLuNDD4airCOlXBurH5bIS9zrDaUqa9UaaReXzpXour2Hyt/w@kd/rvtF2YNMZ818SXVYzuFCHddXF1YNalryQqNuCWvq1XkLDdSUV5yXs70iD83pMagWr0ppmQZxn7kMC3RMkqQSEm7jy@X1bQqOnFGOORvKaVBIC2HCxQ3DFGICQ/pOYCTaokZgQpx5XpA028Ajzuok39rnSHeXo0RYE5@kWpLsFwUbYghxvQeQUrUN@2pYSb9jyaQsip1UdclZD6tOtsNhta6wEn@8Gz7bAF7vBWEbb4MMabNEql@T/FC5KXF@Rfb0TR/u@Rv6BhlOfnZbbnrbeSlW8pq3XIFy7mraThbrl3dL3ao2@kvqxlrrC9jKQaTIgG3RvU@qd2gNtEE9J95hp/vxDQ0nPG5McX107HCyG@LdKeVr9Xwu3rdemWfp@W8oKpLQKvUtq4AW1dG256mg4ol5QG6amShvUdGIzu9FuB9hyoGD@t6OXivIaCWEBL6sshB58PzyFav/4@Gj/9UX39MXJi9MXj@@NK9u@MaEve1P198ae3vwP)

Since knight doesn't have the concept of functions, this program instead takes in the "functions" as strings from standard in and outputs to standard out. Specifically, in `f`, `g`, `x` and `y` on separate lines in input, and outputs `g(f(x),f(y))`. It does this by combining the inputs into a single string, then evaluating (adding appropriate white space).

Comment: It does have a concept of functions. `BLOCK` (`B`). I guess it doesn't work though, because they don't take arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 70 bytes

```go
type i=int
func o(f func(i)i,g func(i,i)i,l,r i)i{return g(f(l),f(r))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZFBasMwEEXp0j7FkJVkRi0xBEoh26xzBdmRjKgtu6oUCCFn6AG6MYUeokdpT9OR7NBFgxGDRuLNn6_R-0fTj1-DrJ9lo6CTxuamG3rnYaU7v_oMXovH750_DQrM1lif62Br6JmGmDDDDTZzivHQogPaz0754Cw0TLOWo2aO88uk9nP3ljRiM8bhnGf9UTl42kKfZ68vQToVD0lTArXkFFc9WcgLUaH6Q7D6B4mKoDpUy0KFFCnEeqbLJdGqSEtMhSmjMnNQ1ht_WmhE1MEcF_0-kN88o4Hf7x3dt5bFkbBpGAj0XARRIpSc38CidYT0AMLWMW5yV68I5CcKbhA2RM7_Mo7T_gs)

`int` shows up enough here to be aliased into a single character and save 3 bytes.

#### [Go](https://go.dev), generic, 66 bytes

```go
func o[T any](f func(T)T,g func(T,T)T,l,r T)T{return g(f(l),f(r))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZFBasMwEEXp0j7FkJVkRi0xBEqhm5ygC-9KFrJjGVFbTlQpEEJu0V03ptBD9CjtaTqSHbpoMGKQZnj68zV6_2j64WsnqxfZ1NBJbVLd7XrrYKE6t_j0Ton777XypoL-uQBpjhumIOSs4AU20xFD0qIF2k-2dt4aaJhiLUfFLOfnUenn5i1KhUaMwylN-kNt4eGRxLVxmzR53Xtp61CJwhKozCkuojKTZ6J8-Ydg-Q8SJUGVL-eFMiliiOVE53OiZRaXGC_GE13T29o47Y4zjYja6sOs3zvymyY08dsnS_XWsDAXNg4DgZ6LIHKEnPMrWLCOEB9A2DLEVe7iFYH8BMEVworI6XOGYdx_AQ)

Usually, generic solutions in Go are longer than the non-generic version. In this case, it's 4 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 22 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan).

```
& &2.(&1.(&3),&1.(&4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@p9fllqkYKvwX01BzUhPQ80QiI01dcC0iabmf09/vYLSkmIFkDKgUGJSsb6hjoKatr6RjoIuCJtr/gcA)

Comment: you don't need the outer ring of parentheses, `& &2.(&1.(&3),&1.(&4))` saves a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
^2∩^1
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=T3ZlciEhIOKGkCBeMuKIqV4xCgpPdmVyISErKMOXLikxIDIKT3ZlciEhLSjDly4pMiDCrzIKT3ZlciEhw7fiiJg1IMKvMjUK)

```
^2∩^1
  ∩^1  # call the unary function on both inputs
^2     # call the binary function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 15 bytes

```
(λ(f g)g&[f f])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMGCpaUlaboWGzTO7dZIU0jXTFeLTlNIi9WECENlYaoA)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 16 bytes

```
4Rdsfxsrlfxlr3Rx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclBCsIwEAXQfU7xwbUI0V6kLkOUoUlQSDphJpXcPmqh2/fCMty4zUFTV8mpZ7nOfXhowelOn4j2ilDOW3vzClIQCi3CSCwIsfCqTWjPuklljWqMsw8Pd/Z4Wljkgo5q3I8uf5owHTa@)

Takes input as the four preceding items on the stack, and pushes the result onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 3 bytes

J-uby has this as a built-in. `:**` takes a pair of lambdas and returns a lambda that takes two arguments. It can be invoked like `:**[f,g][x,y]`, where `f` and `g` are lambdas and `x` and `y` are arguments to the returned lambda.

```ruby
:**
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVfdjqM2FL7PRZ_hrKYdARNgSCedH23mp1K3aqWqVSv1JsqMDJjEHQIRmBHZJPsiezNS24dqr_ootQ0BjCHZSvUFCT7nfD7_Pnz8I8nc9evfn_1zAgtKV-mNbc8JXWSu5cVL21vHHra_NxmP7Yaxa2MHn-PLy2sXjy5cd3TxlXN9FfiXATp3_avxaOT412iMgrEdZJFnJe7g8yUiEUwgxWEwWMZ-FmJ4x2iDAbDl4wC2oMV0gRMdToCduYpTLGh8mbeagZJ5OoRTdrz3rG9A8FoeCkNNPGS6DjshjCO_PsEwQIv0CpQEEFkkfUJ32ncRxXN2dEUrD831jbTFV2RRssQp-LFC4itnRgqFcl2hc20UfmlnV73hsGF_0wedKhUka4lW2il3sa73wZYqSI55hJb7KvYO1w6aMCgkKIXpDB5rtFOOxtlFJLMkWTddjqwQR3O6gMkEziUlGdFVTKutbumi7yRexV180fhplcSezNiIgSKUT9D0fNbp9kbqFeEdgrx_zMlm6eTauTePYMOUh6vEmqlSNrBEYn4M4rDWO7dI9Bv2aBnrjkwvpVg-NITq7FAlPjDuBL8AUyNb4oimB2qvHTWReil5j3lMHSUK9wS22y5CGMervjJy8ZxEnRS-4ozuy8yY8uNZ1GbGPVFLjq8Ep16G4aE07ZskiZNe6HtyNlFV5aurett7nWlYJ67FXIyTFL9RK62N1tG_3r4FTU65E0hXIaKfVK4VzO1tu9wZThbJSIIAdwViwVzy3tR7HeBBnDxr2fBFV_KnJ2_qbjBSHMfBRgwNXoZQRrn848z0437n4o4s_p_8vT-eiefDdaspZlbZBtY6O6B-KdgOppwkX0vvZRUdnFKHHg0a53chLOKYReR_iQeHEvFoNbLeCHABp0_gsPMr0bbZrPFmR8wVOqohqyU7XU0TPqLwxJZmBPZeTgkPSYLWeofXjiax8LjiL0VY7TsieB3Chy4x3uELM08lweatxH-Lu_uLwu5B7Yc3H8rbg1CcIIpZb6AkhJQiN6xP6mreIUp5X5ZHmr6ByE0weuYOzLnpXFTRVIirgZoIBVux1TlKB_MZaCQitGZn7mYaOSbfLX3frI2oVRfFVSOY_WwlkbTojMnr_fMgl2VNu-jK7EW9ntimlS5IQLX-AO_5JBc1KkY8Bh4jp_DLeunGYWE9ibww89tjdt8VwVc5L1lHr5Fq7OOccmCKGb4NyUmC0jEX3VfM4iPBWmK6iH2tNaiIR2HkT_uZTrKwwfCDQDjIImq5S4dPbo-t1NkvUX3vyaq4IPnMBZttkG4h4PcPG7UDfnspw6uKrzYDAS0AYRswQAZWXmu73uSp86Rh_DuSR9myEUk2XD4tSZSlYDbn1XwSkVBqhrnFdu7kAVl80jVMkbtRBd0s2WYrEnox6Iefv_21mCJvyw8D_IJCpmuI2diEfI0ziCu8YcnXKCXejy4fhivFn6pjKs2qc4LJnxkNzKvfbwyj-PfXxxUEU_M23-SGMdoNWQKwm2OTn613s6kzhNFs0M1gcgZz1Ob40uRsZm46FevaMC5MQVoLEpdjyKbTEKxx7QJ3PITxrFDx9bX4_Rc)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 7 bytes

```
{x y z}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6quUKhUqKrl4kqLNtKyNtayNlIwjgUAUiEGKg==)

Simple. Apply function `y` to all numbers in `z`, then apply function `x` to the result.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question